# Problems Accessing Nested Structs in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to parse out an Azure DevOps API to get work item detail as documented here in the [Azure DevOps API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP).

I can successfully call it but I'm struggling to access fields in the second nested struct. It returns the following, as a brief example:

[image]

My code:

```
<cfset result="#DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)#">

<cfoutput>
  #result.id#, #result.rev#, 
  <!---<cfdump var="#result.fields#">--->
  <cfloop collection="#result.fields#" item="f">
    <cfif not isStruct( result.fields[f] )>
      <cfif not isArray( result.fields[f])>
        #encodeForHTML(f)#, #encodeForHTML(result.fields[f])# <br/>
      </cfif>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

The part that I'm getting hung up on is how to reference System.AreaPath directly, for example. I've tried to reference it like:

`#result.fields[f].[System.AreaPath]#` but I get errors. Is it possible to reference this nested struct by name directly, as well as the other children within it like System.TeamProject?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @mykaf is right.  If you're looping over the struct #result.fields# with 'f' as your item, then f will be the struct members as the loop iterates.  For example, System.AreaPath, System.TeamProject, etc....

So, if you're trying to display the value in "System.AreaPath" *inside* the loop, it would be:

```
#result.fields[f]#
```

Where your original question led us to think you wanted to "reference System.AreaPath directly".  If that were the case, referencing it *outside* the loop, it would be:

```
#result.fields["System.AreaPath"]#
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you. I misinterpreted how to reference the whole collection vs. an element in it. This got me where I wanted to be. Cheers, @CFMLBread.

Answer (score 2):

Try losing the dot after fields[f] and put System.AreaPath in quotes like so:

```
#result.fields["System.AreaPath"]#
```

Comment: Right.  You only need the . if you're NOT using brackets and quotes.  With CF, though, you can easily use the dot notation, as it's case-insensitive.  (Unless you have that turned off, like you can in Lucee.)

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. That is returning the following error:

`No matching property [System.AreaPath] found in [string]`

Comment: Can you show us the exact code you're using and what line is being blamed for the error?

Comment: Sure, I appreciate it @CFMLBread. The code:

`<cfoutput>
  <cfloop collection="#result.fields#" item="f">
    <cfif not isStruct( result.fields[f] )>
      <cfif not isArray( result.fields[f])>
        #result.fields[f]["System.AreaPath"]#
      </cfif>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
 `

Line 5 of that I believe matches your suggestion.

The error:  No matching property [System.AreaPath] found in [string]
50: <cfif not isStruct( result.fields[f] )>
51: <cfif not isArray( result.fields[f])>
52: #result.fields[f]["System.AreaPath"]#
53: </cfif>
54: </cfif>

Comment: What happens if you dump `#result.fields[f]#` right before the error is encountered? From the error message, it sounds like `f` *is* `System.AreaPath` (or another key). You seem to be one step deeper into your struct that you believe.

Comment: You are not following the guidance you have been given: `result.fields[f]["System.AreaPath"]` is not `result.fields["System.AreaPath"]`. In your code (from your comment), `f` *is* `"System.AreaPath"`, so `result.fields[f]["System.AreaPath"]` is effectively `result.fields["System.AreaPath"]["System.AreaPath"]`.